# Query collection and extract number of keywords and sort which document has highest total

Tags: mongodb, count, keyword

I have a collection as shown below. I would like to query the Name which has the highest number of keywords (that I specify such as outstanding, great, etc).

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("561c3ccc4c97f053753f1a78"), 
    "Reviews" : 
    [
        {
        "Ratings" : {
                     "Service" : "4", 
                     "Overall" : "5"
                    }, 
        "Location" : "MIS", 
        "Title" : "“Excellent and great”", 
        "Author" : "JDoe", 
        "ReviewID" : "1", 
        "Date" : "March 30, 2015"
        }, 
       {
        "Ratings" : {
                      "Service" : "4", 
                      "Overall" : "5"  
                     }, 
        "Location" : "WIS", 
        "Title" : "“Excellent and fantastic!”", 
        "Author" : "John Doe", 
        "ReviewID" : "2",  
        "Date" : "March 27, 2016"
       }
    ],

    "Info" : 
    {
    "Name" : "AA",
    "ID" : "0001"
     }
}

{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("561c3ccc4c97f0ytu7289074"), 
    "Reviews" : 
    [
        {
        "Ratings" : {
                     "Service" : "4", 
                     "Overall" : "5"
                    }, 
        "Location" : "VEG", 
        "Title" : "“Not too bad”", 
        "Author" : "JDoe", 
        "ReviewID" : "3", 
        "Date" : "March 30, 2015"
        }, 
       {
        "Ratings" : {
                      "Service" : "4", 
                      "Overall" : "5"  
                     }, 
        "Location" : "NEV", 
        "Title" : "“Outstanding service”", 
        "Author" : "John Doe", 
        "ReviewID" : "4",  
        "Date" : "March 27, 2016"
       }
    ],

    "Info" : 
    {
      "Name" : "BB",
      "ID" : "0002"
     }
}
```

Keywords for the filter in Title: "oustanding", "great", "fantastic"

Expected output:

"AA": Total: 4 outstanding:2 great: 1 fantastic: 1
"BB": Total: 1 outstanding:1

Do i use mapreduce or can i use the aggregate function to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I would really suggest the Aggregation framework for it, the only problem is you want to use a part of the Title sting, there is not yet a operator to do this, there will be in MongoDb 3.4.

Can you save the group / identifier part as a field in the document ?

Comment: i am using Mongodb version 3.2.1. Can I do a  query like in SQL where title is in ('Oustanding','Great','Fantastic')?

Comment: yes a query you can do, but you want to count the totals, that requires processing. Because there is not yet a aggregation function which matches a part of a sting your question is hard to solve using the aggregation framework. The position of the keyword differs in each title. So you could proces and store the keyword during save in a own field. Or create a map-reduce to split and proces. The easiest is to do something during save. so the keyword is saved.

Comment: @HoefMeistert sorry I am a newbie with mongo, and I'm not sure what you mean by "save." how do i emit particular keywords in mapreduce to achieve what i want?